# std::function and std::bind return value

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I'm trying to understand how std::bind and std::function work.
I cannot get the following code to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

void function(int a, float b, std::string const &s)
{
    std::cout << "printing function" << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::bind(&function, 10, 11.1, "hello")();
    std::function<void(int, float, std::string const&)> fun = std::bind(&function, 10, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    fun(0.2, "world");

    return 0;
}
```

the compiler complains that:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:16:69: error: conversion from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (*)(int, float, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&), int, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&>::type {aka std::_Bind<void (*(int, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(int, float, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>}' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void(int, float, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>' requested
  std::function<void(int, float, std::string const&)> fun = std::bind(&function, 10, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

please, can someone explain? and how do I fix this error?

Comment: Once you've bound `a` to `10`, what remains is just `void(float, std::string const&)`.

Comment: Also note, that `std::bind` is deprecated in C++17, and that using lambda is more preferred. `auto fun = [](float a, std::string const& b) { function(10, a, b); };`

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that in modern code, lambdas are always preferable to std::bind now.

Comment: @Zereges `std::bind` is in no way deprecated. `std::bind1st` etc. are deprecated but `std::bind` still has some uses: http://www.sdowney.org/2017/06/why-stdbind-cant-be-formally-deprecated/

Comment: @AlanBirtles You're right, I have no idea why I thought it's deprecated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there, just change the type of `fun` to

```
std::function<void(float, std::string const&)> fun = std::bind(...);
//                ^^ no more int here

fun(0.2, "world");
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ those types must match the above signature
```

Note that you change the function signature when fixing the first function argument of type `int` to the value `10`. Hence, it can't be in the type of the `std::function` instantiation.

Further note that Scott Meyers suggests in Item 34 of Effective Modern C++ to replace the `std::bind` usage with a lambda, e.g.

```
auto fun = [](float b, std::string const& s){ function(10, b, s); };

// Identical invocation:
fun(0.2, "world");
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `auto` there.

Comment: @Zereges That fixes the issue, too, but also shadows the reason for the failure in the first place.

Comment: I'd leave the explanation as is, but also suggest using `auto` instead of complicated return type.

Comment: Darn I'm 5 minutes late.